# SCSS @import using full paths

Tags: css, filepath, sass

I currently have a web application which is using SCSS, symphony, and doctrine amongst other libraries. It's well setup and heavily structured.

We are currently attempting to use Bootstrap.css to style it visually, however it's become quite an issue as we began trying to use SASS/SCSS @import function so we could @extend bootstraps classes. However when attempting to do so, it became problematic.

```
 @import url('/bundles/iccsrpit/sass/css/_bootstrap.scss');
```

The above somewhat works (the code is never actually included in the css file when looking at Firebug. I can click on the path, and it brings me to the file.

```
 @import '/bundles/iccsrpit/sass/css/_bootstrap.scss';
```

Causes a complete break of the CSS file, and I'm not sure why I can't access the file in this manner.

If anyone can offer a solution to this problem, please help!

Thank you,
iRed

Comment: So you converted bootstrap.css to scss?

Comment: Yes. We got it working. Ends up it was just because of the '/...'. Should have been relative to the current directory, not the root!

Comment: great, i was going to say that when importing the sass file make sure it's name starts with an underscore, but don't include the underscore (or the file extension) in the import statement. i.e.  @import 'relative/path/to/bootstrap';